# Why doesn't validation work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, frontend

I have been trying to get some grip on Javascript and jquery. I applied it to my asp.net gridivew controls and it works but i am stuck in VALIDATION part i.e. if BidAmount textbox is empty and ddlWorks index is changed then it should throw error i.e. 'Please enter bid amount' and should not process forward. I have tried mess of code but doesn't work.

Code:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="contentScript" ID="CP" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function (evt, args) {
                $('#CP_MainContentUpdatePanel_gvTenders').delegate('tbody tr td select#ddlWorks', 'change', function () {
                    $thisRow = $(this).parent().parent();
                    var $NitNo = window.btoa(parseInt($thisRow.find('td:eq(0)').text())),
                    $BidAmount = window.btoa($thisRow.find('input[type="text"]').val()),
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What are you doing with `$NitNo` and `$BidAmount`? Looks like they're local variables, so they'll disappear after the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

If u want validation Why not use RequiredFiledValidator
check this out

```
 <ItemTemplate>

  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" />

  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlZone" AutoPostBack="true" Style="max-width: 250px" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="-1" ID="Req_ID" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please Select Zone" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="ddlZone" runat="server" />      

 </ItemTemplate>
```